# CKAN: Including Organisation in Url Path

Tags: url, ckan

In CKAN dataset the Url path is defined as

```
/dataset/<dataset-name>
```

What happens when a dataset in different organisations have the same dataset name?

How can we configure that the organisation appears in the Url path:

```
/dataset/<organisation-name>/<dataset-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new dataset in CKAN you are providing dataset Title, which is only required field on the first page.
This title will be unique across CKAN instance and you will not be able to have two datasets with the same title(name).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I like to configure the organisation in the url path anyway - at least for nice Url's.

Comment: So you will need to remap the routes for datasets and organizations using [IRoutes interface](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html?highlight=iroutes#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IRoutes).